# Accessing and setting iPhone's alarm / User alert on timed interval

Tags: iphone, alert, alarm

Are there any way to access or set iphone's alarm?
Im assuming if this isn't available, the only other way is push notification to alert the user on a timed interval. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no public API's for accessing the calendar or alarms.